# Source control mechanism in SharePoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

since SharePoint designer 2010 updates in to the content database.. there is no direct source control mechanism.

If I want to keep modification in SharePoint Designer 2010 in to TFS... what is the mechanism I should follow.

What is best practice in this case?

Need sincere answer.

Comment: For what reason do you need content in the site stored in TFS? SharePoint's core functionality may already provide what you need in terms of versioning, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is no story for source control in SPD, **period**.  Best practice is to develop your solutions in a Visual Studio solution package.  You can use SPD in a dev site to prototype your solutions, and later move them into Visual Studio, where you'll have full integration with source control, among numerous other benefits.